# Looking for an old movie about Martians crashing ships into Earth to steal secret of landing

Tags: story-identification

Basically the title says all I know. I am trying to find a movie that my father keeps talking about, hopefully I can surprise him with it.  I know very little about the movie other than it is about Martians being very advanced in science and intergalactic space flight, but they never learned how to safely land.  They end up crashing 100s of ships into Earth in the hopes that a couple will survive, and the survivors can steal the secret of successfully landing space craft safely.

Comment: Do you know when he watched it? Was it in English? Can you check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) and see if you can secretly ask him some of those questions?

Comment: Sounds like they came from the "Indiana Jones school of piloting".  Fly yes, land... no.

Comment: The part about the landing reminds me of "Moontrap"